# Securing my home network and computer while still allowing SSH

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I recently built a computer (linux) and am allowing SSH so that I can log in from my macbook while on the couch. Do I need to be concerned about security settings at all and/or what should I look out for?

From the 5 minutes of web searching I did, it seems like it's the home network/router which is the focal point for anyone trying to break in anyway, right? So if they can't break past my password and actually log onto the network, then I'm fine?

Comment: Who else is on your LAN? If your WiFi and router are secure, then `telnet` can suffice in place of `ssh`.  Try checking your firewall security by visiting [ShieldsUp!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)

Comment: just me and my wife! Why telnet over ssh? Just because I won't have to open the ssh port? I've never used telnet before, so I'm unfamiliar with it. Does sftp move over ssh port too? So won't it have to be open for sftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't allow the SSH server to be accessible from outside your network, which it doesn't seem like it is. Then you should be ok. If you want to add increased security from within your network and the SSH server you can lookup using certificates to log in to it.

Generally yes, if the attacker can not get past your router then your network should be safe. But this is with the assumption that you have no ports open or forwarded to something within your network and a decent firewall.

From my experience you should always be concerned with security :)

Comment: Thanks - how do I test this? Do I just need to find my external IP address and try to log in via ssh to my computer? If I can't then it must be ok?

Comment: One way is to use the website [Canyouseme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org/)  and check your ports specifically 22 since you are running ssh. Best way is to use namp and scan your public IP from a different network.

Comment: Usually, router is not forwarding port 22 by default. So you should be ok. If you want to allow only to specific ip, try [This Post](http://serverfault.com/a/207405) from serverfault. The method is editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to allow only specific ip.